# Google API missing

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm desperate. I just want to install a Google MAP API and it should be in my Android SDK Manager...but it's gone suddenly...so I just have Android API's without a Google API. Anyone know how to solve this?
I have updated my Android SDK Tool's too...

So this is link to the image that shows a Google API for android 4.0.3 :

[click here :D](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing.html)

But there's no "Google APIs by Google Inc." in mine (it should be there before, it's suddenly missing)

Thanks :D

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't already installed them?

Comment: With latest updates, it should just say 'Google APIs' not 'Google APIs by Google Inc'. I don't know when it changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED..so this is what happened :
 1. (I think) Eclipse want us to keep updating so when your Android SDK is NOT the latest one then we will need to UPDATE it first so the Google API, USB, etc will appear again. 
 2. After that, we need to upgrade our ADT in help->check for update so the Eclipse can work with the new Android SDK.
 3. After did that things, the Google API, USB, etc is appeared again and can be installed :D